# Cant install/compile utorrent from tar.gz source

Tags: 11.04, installation, compiling, bittorrent

I tried to install/compile utorrent like that:

```
sudo ./configure
make
make install
```

and like that:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/path
make
make install
```

and like that:

```
sudo ./configure --enable-static-link \
--prefix=$XXX/static --with-curses &&
make &&
make install
```

and it didn't work!

I get Error: `./configure: No such file or directory.`

Comment: Is there any uTorrent client or did you install uTorrent server? I can't see any client package for Linux on its site. And server package is not a source file, it is a binary. That means you can't compile it.

Comment: If you open the source map, can you find a configure file in it? if not, then the error is correct. They might have spelled it in a strange way! Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

you need to go to the source of the tar.gz via the command `cd`. So if you have it on the Desktop it could be something like this:

```
cd Desktop/
```

When you start a terminal you are in the directory `home`.

So if I wanted to do the first type of command I would:

```
cd Desktop/FILE

./configure

make

make install
```

the `./` command just tells the console that you will start in the current folder. with `../` you go **up** one folder.

Comment: i try to do cd/desktop/"folder file name after extract" and than ./configure and it didnt work.. same Error

Comment: is there a file that is listed as "configure" ? normally you should  use the command "cd" to navigate to a folder which contains a configure file and a install file. If you find that folder try the commands again with that folder as source.